# How to Vertically Centre an Image in a Vertically Merged Cell

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment, alignment

I am trying to centre an image within a table so that it is centered vertically within the table between two rows.

Here is an image of what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

But I want it for the picture to be located at the same height as the Number 1 to the left of it.

Here is the code used:

```
\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{96,162,216}
\definecolor{mblue}{RGB}{208,221,240}
\definecolor{lblue}{RGB}{233,239,247}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{lblue}{mblue}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|c|l|c|c|c|l|@{}}\rowcolor{dblue}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Iteration} & {\color[HTML]{000000} Design}     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Max Stress} &     \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Max Deflection} & Comment \\ \midrule
                            &            \includegraphics[align=c,scale=0.125]{Ben/Pictures/aircraft-bearing-bracket-FEM.jpg}                           & Case 1                & XX                              & XX                                  &     XX    \\ \cmidrule(l){3-6} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{1}             & \multirow{-2}{*}{}            & Case 2                & XX                              & XX                                  &    XX     \\ \midrule
                            &                               & Case 1                & XX                              & XX                                  &     XX    \\ \cmidrule(l){3-6} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{2}             & \multirow{-2}{*}{}            & Case 2                & XX                              & XX                                  &  XX       \\ \midrule
                            &                               & Case 1                & XX                              & XX                                  &    XX     \\ \cmidrule(l){3-6} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{3}             & \multirow{-2}{*}{}            & Case 2                & XX                              & XX                                  &  XX        \\ \midrule
                            &                               & Case 1                & XX                              & XX                                  &   XX      \\ \cmidrule(l){3-6} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{4}             & \multirow{-2}{*}{}            & Case 2                & XX                              & XX                                  &  XX       \\ \midrule
                            &                               & Case 1                & XX                              & XX                                  &   XX      \\ \cmidrule(l){2-6} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{5}             &                               & Case 2                & XX                              & XX                                  &  XX       \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you use `\multirow{-2}{*}{}` where you *want* the vertically centered image, and you place the image itself in the second row of the table without trying to put it in a multirow. Compilable example (the packages and options are guesses, based on commands in your table):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{duckuments}%for the duck image
\begin{document}
\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{96,162,216}
\definecolor{mblue}{RGB}{208,221,240}
\definecolor{lblue}{RGB}{233,239,247}


\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{lblue}{mblue}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|c|l|c|c|c|l|@{}}\rowcolor{dblue}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Iteration} & {\color[HTML]{000000} Design}     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Max Stress} &     \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Max Deflection} & Comment \\ \midrule
&                                       & Case 1                & XX                              & XX                                  &     XX    \\ \cmidrule(l){3-6} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{1}             & \multirow{-2}{*}{\hfil\includegraphics[align=c,scale=.125]{example-image-duck}\hfil}            & Case 2                & XX                              & XX                                  &    XX     \\ \midrule
&                               & Case 1                & XX                              & XX                                  &     XX    \\ \cmidrule(l){3-6} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{2}             & \multirow{-2}{*}{}            & Case 2                & XX                              & XX                                  &  XX       \\ \midrule
&                               & Case 1                & XX                              & XX                                  &    XX     \\ \cmidrule(l){3-6} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{3}             & \multirow{-2}{*}{}            & Case 2                & XX                              & XX                                  &  XX        \\ \midrule
&                               & Case 1                & XX                              & XX                                  &   XX      \\ \cmidrule(l){3-6} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{4}             & \multirow{-2}{*}{}            & Case 2                & XX                              & XX                                  &  XX       \\ \midrule
&                               & Case 1                & XX                              & XX                                  &   XX      \\ \cmidrule(l){2-6} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{5}             &                               & Case 2                & XX                              & XX                                  &  XX       \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample of MWE]

Comment: Thanks for your help! This has solved the problem. One issue that still arises is that I cant seem to get the text to wrap. It just goes off the page. Cheers!

Comment: Text in your comment field? You might want to switch that column type from `c` to `p{<width of the column>}`, and specify the width you want the column to have. The wikibook page may be of more use on this, as it describes options for vertically or horizontally centering the text. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Answer (score 1):

i suspect that you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{96,162,216}
\definecolor{mblue}{RGB}{208,221,240}
\definecolor{lblue}{RGB}{233,239,247}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\rowcolors{2}{lblue}{mblue}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|c|l|c|c|c|l|@{}}
    \rowcolor{dblue}
    \toprule
Iteration
    & Design    &           & Max Stress    & Max Deflection    & Comment   \\
    \midrule
    &           & Case 1    & XX            & XX                & XX        \\
    \cmidrule(l){3-6}
\multirow{-2.4}{*}{1}
    & \multirow{-2.4}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25, valign=c]{example-image-duck}}
                & Case 2    & XX            & XX                & XX        \\
    \midrule
    &           & Case 1    & XX            & XX                & XX        \\ 
    \cmidrule(l){3-6}
\multirow{-2.4}{*}{2}
    & \multirow{-2.4}{*}{image?}
                & Case 2    & XX            & XX                &  XX       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

however, look of this table is awful (to my taste, of course). i would remove all vertical lines, the most of horizontal rules and colors:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c cc c c l @{}}
    \toprule
Iteration
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Design}           
                            & Max Stress    & Max Deflection    & Comment   \\
    \midrule
    &           & Case 1    & XX            & XX                & XX        \\
\multirow{-2.1}{*}{1}
    & \multirow{-2.1}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2, valign=c]{example-image-duck}}
                & Case 2    & XX            & XX                & XX        \\
    \addlinespace
    &           & Case 1    & XX            & XX                & XX        \\ 
\multirow{-2.1}{*}{2}
    & \multirow{-2.1}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2, valign=c]{example-image-duck}}
                & Case 2    & XX            & XX                & XX        \\
    \addlinespace
    &           & Case 1    & XX            & XX                & XX        \\
\multirow{-2.1}{*}{3}        
    & \multirow{-2.1}{*}{image?}
                & Case 2    & XX            & XX                &  XX       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! This has solved the problem. One issue that still arises is that I cant seem to get the text to wrap. It just goes off the page. Cheers!

Comment: which text? from your question this is not evident this problem. you should ask new question. also seeing https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/ could help in tables design ...